# Creating a secure login page for a multi-page administration panel

Tags: javascript, html, css, panel, administration

I'm looking to create a login page to secure and encrypt user passwords for a multi-page administration panel. But here's the catch, I do not want to use PHP. I'm fine with using programming languages such as HTML, JavaScript and it's counterparts, but I simply want an encrypted login page without PHP. I want to have multiple username's and password's. I am also a learning web developer. Any help or links to any tutorials are much appreciated!

Comment: This is very broad (and requests for tutorial/off-site-material recommendations are off topic), so I expect it will be closed shortly. If you have a specific question about a problem you are encountering while building your administration panel, that would be a better suited question for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of server-side component for a login page.

There are more options than just PHP, but HTML and Javascript won't cut it -- those are both client-side languages. (Unless you actually mean a Javascript server environment like node.js, but given the context I don't think that's what you mean.)